# cannot update model: it has no pk in windows phone 8.1 c#

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

I have a model class shown below.

```
public class Section
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int section_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime syncTime { get; set; }
}
```

When i try to update I get the error message as Cannot update Section: it has no PK

Below is my update Code

```
async public Task<bool> UpdateSection_SyncTime(int section_Id)
{
    try
    {
        var sections = await db.Table<Section>().ToListAsync();

        foreach (var section in sections)
        {
            if(section.section_id == section_Id)
            {
                section.syncTime = DateTime.Now;    // Update the Section Sync Time

                if (await db.UpdateAsync(section) >= 1)
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }
    return false;
}
```

The exception is thrown in SQLite.cs file with the error.

Answer (score 0):

i hope a slight modification in code can fix the issue

```
foreach (var section in sections)
        {
            if(section.section_id == section_Id)
            {

                section.syncTime = DateTime.Now;    // Update the Section Sync Time
                App.DBConnection.Update(section); //update the db

                if (await db.UpdateAsync(section) >= 1)
                    return true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: should I use non-async method and do I need to open and close the connection I mean the preferred approach that should be used.

Comment: I tried using SQLiteConnection sqlConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DBPath);  sqlConn.Update(section);     But still same problem.

Comment: It solved actually I was using [SQLite.Net.Attributes.PrimaryKey] I saw in some site using 

[SQLite.PrimaryKey] so after using this namespace it doesn't give the error.

But what's the difference between both the namespaces.